# Integrating Service Stack into Custom Server

Tags: servicestack

I have a custom HTTP server written in C# that provides specialized application services in my application domain, such as rendering a dashboard with graphing.  I am not using IIS; the server is completely written in C# using the `HttpListener` class to bind directly to the port(s) that it serves.

I would like to use ServiceStack to add in a RESTful API for pulling data to browser-side code to improve the user experience, using the same web server (so it can bind to the same HTTPS port, and share my security module).

All of the example code on the web that I have found assumes either that IIS owns the web port, or that Service Stack owns the web port.  In my use case, my custom application owns the web port, and wants to delegate certain HTTP requests to Service Stack.

Is there a simple way to pass off a single `HttpListenerContext` off to Service Stack to handle?  I could not find documentation examples using google, since all of the key words seem to be too common.

In the context of my custom code, I will have already evaluated the URL, determined that the user has permission to access it, and just need to have `HttpListenerResponse` generated.

Simple sample code or a pointer to a web article would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've never tested doing this before, but the [AppHostHttpListenerBase.ProcessRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/AppHostHttpListenerBase.cs#L39) entry point accepts a `HttpListenerContext`.

You would still need to call `new AppHost().Init()` but you shouldn't need to start it.

Comment: Looking at the source of the method you linked, that makes a lot of sense, and I don't see why it wouldn't work...  I will try it.

Comment: It does seem to work, in preliminary testing.   I added a public method to the `AppHost` in the console example code that calls `ProcessRequest()`, since that is protected.